# Local notifications with "cordova-plugin-local-notifications" plugin

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, cordova-plugins, localnotification

I am trying to add the cordova-plugin-local-notifications plugin to my android project.

I am adding `implementation 'com.github.katzer:cordova-plugin-local-notification'`under dependencies, into my app gradle file. But Gradle can't find the plugin.

Error: `Supplied String module notation 'Failed to resolve: com.github.katzer:cordova-plugin-local-notification:`

Plugin link: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you executed ``cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-local-notification`` ?

Comment: @heroin: it throws error  ` 'cordova' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow steps from tutorial:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/

Here you may find how to install Android if not yet:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#requirements-and-support

and how to install plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't installed the plugin properly. You have not even installed the Cordova CLI properly, according to your comments.

If you are new to Cordova, I strongly recommend you to try an IDE like [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/features/mobile-app-development/) with the tools for Apache Cordova and set it up following [this guide](https://www.andreszsogon.com/visual-studio-2017-and-apache-cordova-mobile-apps/). Plugins must be properly installed before they can be used in your apps, and of course Cordova needs to be installed first.